# How to create a label function that updates each label created?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have created a function that creates labels in tkinter. The goal of my function is to create labels that update themselves upon new calculated values to display. I have the following code:

```
def display_values(self, attribute, type, r, c, cs):
    try:
        if self.display_label:
            self.display_label.destroy()
    except AttributeError:
        lambda *args: None
    self.display_label = tk.Label(self.parent, text=str(attribute) + " (" + type + ")")
    self.display_label.grid(row=r, column=c, columnspan=cs, sticky=tk.W)
```

This works perfectly fine if I only create one label using the function. If I create multiple labels using this function, whenever a label is updated, the function may destroy another label, not the label that was updated upon. How would I fix this?

Comment: to update a label you can use `display_label.config(text=str(attribute) + " (" + type + ")")`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're `destroy`ing the last set `Label` in `self.display_label`, you need a way to differentiate the `Labels` you create, for instance saving them in a `dict`ionary, and also have a different method for updating any arbitrary `Label`.

```python
def create_labels(self, attribute, type, r, c, cs, Key):
    try:
        self.Labels
    except:
        self.Labels = dict()
    self.Labels[Key] = tk.Label(self.parent, text = '{} ({})'.format(str(attribute),type))
    self.Labels[Key].grid(row=r, column=c, columnspan=cs, sticky=tk.W)

def update_labels(self, Key, Value):
    self.Labels[Key]['text'] = '{}'.format(Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are destroying and recreating the labels not updating them.
Once you create a label you can update it easily without destroying it by using it's config method.

```
my_label = Label(parent, text='Hello')    #<-- Create a label

my_label.config(text='Bye')       #<-- update label
```

So in your code you could do something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

# Your updating function

def update_labels(labels, new_info):
    for l in labels:
        l.config(text=new_info)


from functools import partial   #<-- use partial to pass arguments from button event

tk = Tk()

# Create my label
my_label = Label(text='Hello')
my_label.pack()

# To update my label
my_label.config(text='bye')

# So you could make a list of labels, and then update that list

labels = []
for l in range(10):
    lbl = Label(text=l)
    lbl.pack()
    labels.append(lbl)


# A button that updates all labels, example

b = Button(text='Update', command=partial(update_labels, labels, 'hi'))
b.pack()


mainloop()
```

Now you oviously would want to update each label with different data.
For that add each label to a dictionary with diferent key name

```
labels = {}
for l in range(10):
    labels[l] = Label(text=l)
    labels[l].pack()
```

create your updating function

```
def update_label(label, new_info):
    label.config(new_info)
```

And then use the label key name to access it from the labels dictionary

```
label = labels[2]
```

and then call your update_label function

```
update_label(label, 'new info here')
```